# Conflict primary key

Tags: mysql, jpa

I'm developing an application with JPA.
I have a problem if I populate the database before I start the application. 
If I do this first, I can not insert a tuple in the database using user interface of my developed application because the table is already populated. For example I populate my table with sql script using primary keys from 1 to 5. Why the application does not restart to insert the new tuple from 6? 
The strategy I use to generate ID is

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Comment: AUTO means: choose the best strategy given the underlying database/table. Look at the generated SQL, and tell us which database you use, to know how JPA generates the IDs. It probably uses a sequence or a table, and the sequenceor table is not initialized with the correct value given what you already have in the database.

Comment: I use InnoDB. I also tried to use this command but It doesn't work            ALTER TABLE VOLO MODIFY ID_VOLO ID_VOLO decimal(38,0) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY; VOLO is my table and ID_VOLO my primary key column

Comment: telling "it doesn't work" doesn't help us helping you. be precise. Describe what you did, what you expected the result to be, and what it was instead. Paste exact and complete error messages.

Comment: ok, sorry, I will write in more than one comment because the post Is too long. this is my table

Comment: I've got a table volo with primari key not null bigdecimal(38,0) the column id_volo, If I try to do the command I write over here this is the error ERROR 1063 (42000): Incorrect column specifier for column 'ID_VOLO'. The name of columns is right, if I do the command describe volo; the name of columns is just ID_VOLO

Comment: Edit your question. There is an edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Make your primary key id auto increment and then use this annotation:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Did you also use the `@Id` annotation?